# How to insert sourcecode?

Tags: listings, sourcecode

For my internship, I have to print all the source of my iOS application to a LaTeX file. Now I'd like to do this in a structured way by having sections, subsections and subsubsections for each nested folder... Code will not be nested beyond 3 levels. Wait let me compare a folder structure to what I want.

This folder structure:

```
|____Source-master
| |____folderA
| | |____fileC.swift
| |____folderB
| | |____fileA.swift
| | |____folderC
| | | |____fileB.h
| | | |____fileB.m
```

Should become this LaTeX code:

```
\section{Source-master}
\subsection{folderA}
\lstinputlisting{fileC.swift}
\subsection{folderB}
\lstinputlisting{fileC.swift}
\subsubsection{folderC}
\lstinputlisting{fileC.h}
\lstinputlisting{fileC.m}
```

How can I convert the files from the filesystem into this format? Do I need a script or is there a package I can import that will provide a command like `\insertSourceRecursively{foldername}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! So what is your question?

Comment: And your question is? (you need the folder prefix on each of the included files)

Comment: @Andrew How can I convert the files from the filesystem into this format? Do I need a script or is there a package I can import that will provide a command like `\insertSourceRecursively{foldername}`? I'll add it into the question.

Comment: @daleif edited question

Comment: Standard LaTeX does not know about the file system and thus cannot traverse it. Perhaps lualatex can. Exactly how many files do you have? Unless the number is huge, it is a lot faster to just write those paths by hand.

Comment: It's quite extensive. Think about 50 source files, in a nice compact hierarchy. I think I might just write a little script that traverses this and outputs the above text...

Comment: I'd write a script as you say, outputting a .tex file that can be `\input` at the appropriate moment.  Personally I'd use python but anything that can walk the file system will do the job.

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: @Jubobs My main machine is a mac, I own a windows with multiple linux VMs, so pretty much all of them ;)

Comment: @user1009013 So a portable Unix shell script would do, I guess.

Comment: That's certainly doable in Lua with LuaTeX, but with the other engines you'll need an external program that creates the TeX document as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I took the OP's stated problem too literally in order to accomplish this.  But since I am not accessing the disk directory structure in order to ascertain whether an entry is a file or a folder, I relied (as given by the OP's MWE) that folder names begin with "folder" and filenames begin with "file".  While I could develop other schemes, the problem persists that the input stream will have to, in some way, indicate to the parser whether the object is a file or a folder. See ADDENDUM.

That said, I made `|` active and set about parsing.  I generate errors if the file structure attempts to go below the `\subsection` level.  Also, since I really didn't have files by these names, I just print the word "lstinputlisting" followed by the relative filename, instead of actually invoking a listing macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand\setlisting[2][]{lstinputlisting \csname Level#1\endcsname/#2}
\catcode`|=\active%
\def|#1____#2#3#4 {%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax%
    \section{#2#3#4}\def\LevelA{#2#3#4}%
  \else%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{ |}}}%
    {\if o#3\subsection{#2#3#4}\def\LevelB{\LevelA/#2#3#4}%
       \else \setlisting[A]{#2#3#4}\fi}%
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{ | |}}}%
      {\if o#3\subsubsection{#2#3#4}\def\LevelC{\LevelB/#2#3#4}%
         \else \setlisting[B]{#2#3#4}\fi}%
      {\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{ | | |}}}%
        {\if o#3 ERROR: DIRECTORY LEVEL {#2#3#4} TOO DEEP%
           \else \setlisting[C]{#2#3#4}\fi}%
        {ERROR: {#2#3#4} TOO DEEP}%
      }%
    }%
  \fi\par%
}%
\catcode`|=12
\newenvironment{filetree}{\catcode`|=\active}{}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
\begin{filetree}
|____Source-master
| |____folderA
| | |____fileC.swift
| |____folderB
| | |____fileA.swift
| | |____folderC
| | | |____fileB.h
| | | |____fileB.m
| | | |____folderD
| | | | |____fileD
\end{filetree}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**ADDENDUM**

As indicated, my parser needs some guidance on what is a directory versus a file.  In this alternate implementation, there is no requirement on the naming convention of files and folders themselves.  However, directory names must be preceded by an asterisk `*` in the input argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand\setlisting[2][]{lstinputlisting \csname Level#1\endcsname/#2}
\catcode`|=\active%
\def|#1____#2#3#4 {%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax%
    \section{#3#4}\def\LevelA{#3#4}%
  \else%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{ |}}}%
    {\if *#2\subsection{#3#4}\def\LevelB{\LevelA/#3#4}%
       \else \setlisting[A]{#2#3#4}\fi}%
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{ | |}}}%
      {\if *#2\subsubsection{#3#4}\def\LevelC{\LevelB/#3#4}%
         \else \setlisting[B]{#2#3#4}\fi}%
      {\ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{ | | |}}}%
        {\if *#2 ERROR: DIRECTORY LEVEL {#3#4} TOO DEEP%
           \else \setlisting[C]{#2#3#4}\fi}%
        {ERROR: {#2#3#4} TOO DEEP}%
      }%
    }%
  \fi\par%
}%
\catcode`|=12
\newenvironment{filetree}{\catcode`|=\active}{}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
\begin{filetree}
|____*Source-master
| |____*DirectoryA
| | |____fileC.swift
| |____*MyfolderB
| | |____fileA.swift
| | |____*folderC
| | | |____fileB.h
| | | |____fileB.m
| | | |____*folderD
| | | | |____fileD
\end{filetree}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user1009013  Glad to help.  It was fun.